# VBA Macro to merge cells seperated by commas and ignore blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

I need a vba macro to merge cells from one row separated by commas into one new cell and ignore blank cells, because sometimes I get eg. image1,image2,image3,,,,,

**Heres an example:**
|      **IMAGE_1**      |      **IMAGE_2**      |           **MERGED_IMAGES**             |
|   myimage1.jpg   |   myimage2.jpg   |   myimage1.jpg,myimage2.jpg       |
| myimage1_b.jpg | myimage2_b.jpg | myimage1_b.jpg,myimage2_b.jpg |
| myimage1_c.jpg | myimage2_c.jpg |  myimage1_c.jpg,myimage2_c.jpg |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally i have found a solution with this formula:**

```
=IF(A1=0;"";A1&",") & IF(B1=0;"";B1&",") & IF(C1=0;"";C1)
```

**Ok this is the new macro that works:**

```
    Columns("AD:AD").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Range("AD2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-10]=0,"""",RC[-10]&"","") & IF(RC[-9]=0,"""",RC[-9]&"","") & IF(RC[-8]=0,"""",RC[-8]&"","") & IF(RC[-7]=0,"""",RC[-7]&"","") & IF(RC[-6]=0,"""",RC[-6]&"","") & IF(RC[-5]=0,"""",RC[-5]&"","") & IF(RC[-4]=0,"""",RC[-4]&"","") & IF(RC[-3]=0,"""",RC[-3]&"","") & IF(RC[-2]=0,"""",RC[-2]&"","") & IF(RC[-1]=0,"""",RC[-1])"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AD2:AD" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("AD2:AD" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select

Selection.Copy
Range("AE2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("AD:AD,AC:AC,AB:AB,AA:AA,Z:Z,Y:Y,X:X,W:W,V:V,U:U,T:T").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

**info**

> This Macro Merge Columns T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC into AD Column and separates values by comma and ignores blank cells. After that it copies the results into AE Column and deletes the unnecessary Columns. So when the macro executes completely you have all this Columns merged into T Column

**Heres an example:**
|      **IMAGE_1**      |      **IMAGE_2**      |           **MERGED_IMAGES**             |
|   myimage1.jpg   |   myimage2.jpg   |   myimage1.jpg,myimage2.jpg       |
| myimage1_b.jpg | myimage2_b.jpg | myimage1_b.jpg,myimage2_b.jpg |
| myimage1_c.jpg | myimage2_c.jpg |  myimage1_c.jpg,myimage2_c.jpg |

**PS!!!**
I have found a second problem, after the macro executes i have found some cells with an unneeded comma in the end of the cell value.
So i have create a second macro to fix that problem with the macro recorder and this formula

```
=IF(RIGHT(J2;1)=",";LEFT(J2;LEN(J2)-1);J2)
```

You can change the formula to whatever you want, eg if you want to remove the "w" character in the end of the value of A2 cell you can change the formulla like this:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A2;1)="w";LEFT(A2;LEN(A2)-1);A2)
```